# How to replace navbar brand with icon when collapsed in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

New to boostrap here. So how do you replaced the navbar brand with icon (icons from Fontawesome for example) or custom image logo when the navbar enters collapsed mode in Bootstrap 4?

My code are as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<!-- <div class="container">  --><!-- you can turn this container off/on-->
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Anime Battlegrounds</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <!-- collapse class will hide everything in the navbar once we hit mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Popular</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Anime List</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Schedule</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Login</a>
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0 btn1" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 [display utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) that correspond with the navbar breakpoint.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/9KbjsZ6pGP

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
   <span class="d-lg-inline-block d-none">Anime Battlegrounds</span>
   <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block d-lg-none"></i>
</a>
```

`d-lg-inline-block d-none` means display on lg and up, hide (`d-none`) below lg
`d-inline-block d-lg-none` means hide on lg and up, display (`d-inline-block`) below lg

Comment: Thanks! Either way it works both on icon and img tag.

Answer (score 2):

here examples (if I understood your question correctly)

e.g. (more icons in doc for fontawesome)

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
   <i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
</a>
```

don't forget within head-tag:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

or:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
       <img src="./image1.gif" />
</a>
```

Comment: Another easy method that doesn't require a text within `navbar-brand` .Thanks!